# How i can change the image name before uploading it to folder?

Tags: php, html

can someone please help i just need to change the image name before uploading it to folder.
whatever user type in here:

```
<input  name="yname" placeholder="Your Name"class="input-group-field" >
```

the file name will be changed to given name.
 html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <h3>Select image to upload:<br></br></h3>
    <input  name="yname" placeholder="Your Name"class="input-group-field" ><br>
    <input type="file" class="button" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload Images" name="submit">
</form>
<button class ="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'showimgs.php';">show images</button>
```

php

```
<?php

$target_dir = "photos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
   if($check !== false) {
       echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
       $uploadOk = 1;
   } else {
       echo "File is not an image.";
       $uploadOk = 0;
   }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
   echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
   echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
   } else {
       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
   }
}

Echo "<b><button class=button onclick=location.href='images.html'>Click here to go back</button></b>";
?>
```

I am beginner and this is not my own php code.
edited.
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

Comment: Change it to WHAT?

Comment: Change this `basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])` to whatever you want to rename the file as. _Small Point_ Copying some code from the internet is fine to get you started, but you really ought to spend a little time making sure you know what AND HOW it is doing whatever it is doing. Otherwise you may well end up adding hacks to your site accidentally

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what you are trying to do or why you are doing it, as you haven't provided full details of what you want to change to or why, but here is the code :

```
<?php

$filename = "YOUR_FILE_NAME";

$target_dir = "photos/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
   if($check !== false) {
       echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
       $uploadOk = 1;
   } else {
       echo "File is not an image.";
       $uploadOk = 0;
   }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
   echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
   echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
   echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
       echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
   } else {
       echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
   }
}

Echo "<b><button class=button onclick=location.href='images.html'>Click here to go back</button></b>";
?>
```